# how to print specific value using while loop in codeigniter view page?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to print the value where country name is Canada. using foreach I have got the all value. In the while loop I restrict the value that which I want to print.  are there any error in this line==> ins_country = "Canada"): ?>

```
           <div style="width: 100%">
            <?php foreach ($ins as $i) { ?>
                <?php while ($i->ins_country = "Canada"): ?>
                    <div class="lop_div">
                        <h2> <?php echo $i->ins_country; ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $i->ins_name; ?><br>

                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php }
            ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of while use if condition:

```
        <?php foreach ($ins as $i) { ?>

            <?php if ($i->ins_country = "Canada"): ?>

                <div class="lop_div">
                    <h2> <?php echo $i->ins_country; ?></h2>
                    <?php echo $i->ins_name; ?><br>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: you are partial ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="width: 100%">
                <?php foreach ($ins as $i) { ?>
                    <?php if ($i->ins_country == "Canada"){ ?>
                        <div class="lop_div">
                            <?php echo $i->ins_country;?>;
                            <?php echo $i->ins_name; ?><br>

                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php }
                ?>
            </div>
```